# comparison GCD vs. performSelectorInBackground: dispatch_async not in background

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, background, grand-central-dispatch, performselector

Grand Central Dispatch is great and reduces the amount of code but why I cannot run something on a background thread?
I have made a sample application to show what I mean (none of the commented work):

```
- (IBAction)performSel {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doStuff) withObject:nil];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
    [[self.view.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
}

- (IBAction)gcd {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("myGCDqueue", NULL), ^(void) {
    //dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_create("myGCDqueue", NULL), ^(void) {
    //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
    //dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
    //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    //dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [self doStuff]; // only for readability, will move the code on success
    });
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
    [[self.view.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)doStuff {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    UIView *abortingView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];
    abortingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    abortingView.alpha = 0.7;
    [self.view insertSubview:abortingView atIndex:10];
    [abortingView release];

    [pool drain];
}
```

the `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];` is to simulate a default UI functionality. For example if someone is switching from one navigation view to another.
Simply copy the code in a new view based application, create two buttons and connect them.

Comment: sleeping or doing long-running tasks in response to IBAction-methods is always a bad idea

Answer (score 24, accepted):

UIKit classes should be used only from an application’s main thread. (From iOS4, drawing to a graphics context is thread-safe.) You can't use UIKit stuff in a background thread.

Thus, you can only use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block) in this situation.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
```

It will invoke the block on the main thread in the runloop of the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("myGCDqueue", NULL), ^(void) {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
```

It will invoke the block in a background thread. You can't use it because you want to use UIKit in the block. And be careful **dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create(**, it might cause memory leak, you have to release the serial queue that is created by dispatch_queue_create.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_create("myGCDqueue", NULL), ^(void) {
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
```

dispatch_sync waits until the block is done.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
```

It causes DEADLOCK.

Comment: you shouldn't use `dispatch_queue_create("myGCDqueue", NULL)` like that because you'd be leaking. you have to release queue you created at some point - usually after dispatching some block onto it